# MockRestServiceServer test sending a file upload through Multipart-formdata

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method that sends a rest request to an api with multipart-formdata, this will upload a file to the external api. However, I am not able to finish the unit test method for this.

The first problem I am finding is that the content-type that I am expecting is always different than the one that method create. For some reason when sending the request the mediatype is multipart-formdata but the header is set as that in addition to charset and boundary. The latter, boundary, is always changing its value therefore I can not set the expected value on the unit tests because it will always be different.

Apart from that, how do I also expect that the content of the request is the same content that I initiated the test with? How do I assert that the payload is the same.

Please check the code:

Service class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class JiraService {

    private HttpHeaders createRequestHeaders(JiraClient jiraClient, MediaType contenType) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(contenType);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setBasicAuth(jiraClient.getUsername(), jiraClient.getPassword());

        return headers;
    }

    private <EC, RC> ResponseEntity<RC> createRequestAndSend(HttpMethod method, String url, HttpHeaders headers,
            EC payload, Class<RC> responseType) {
        HttpEntity<EC> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);
        ResponseEntity<RC> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType);
        // TODO deal with response

        log.error("Loggin something");

        return responseEntity;
    }

    public void addAttachment(JiraClient jiraClient, JiraIssue jiraIssue, JiraAttachment jiraAttachment)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = jiraClient.getHost() + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + jiraIssue.getKey() + "/attachments";

        HttpHeaders headers = createRequestHeaders(jiraClient, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA); // What to do here?
        headers.set("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check");

        FileSystemResource file = jiraAttachment.downloadFileFromWeb();
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> payload = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        payload.add("file", file);

        createRequestAndSend(HttpMethod.POST, url, headers, payload, String.class);

        jiraAttachment.deleteFileFromSystem();
    }
}
```

ServiceTest.class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RestClientTest(JiraService.class)
public class JiraServiceTest {

  @Value("classpath:jira/add_attachment/validJiraAttachmentAddition.json")
  private Resource validJiraAttachmentAddition;

  @Autowired
  private MockRestServiceServer server;
  @Autowired
  private JiraService jiraService;

  @Mock
  private JiraAttachment mockJiraAttachment;

  private FileSystemResource attachmentFileSystemResource;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setupTests() throws IOException {
      // initialize mocks
  }

  @Test
  public void addAttachment_WithValidData_ShouldAddAttachmentToJiraIssue() throws Exception {
    String url = host + "/rest/api/2/issue/" + issueKey + "/attachments";

    ResponseActions stub = createServiceStub(HttpMethod.POST, url, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);
    stub = stub.andExpect(header("X-Atlassian-Token", "no-check"));
    stub.andRespond(withSuccess());
    // How to assert that the content of the request is the same as the resource?

    when(mockJiraAttachment.downloadFileFromWeb()).thenReturn(attachmentFileSystemResource);

    jiraService.addAttachment(mockJiraClient, mockJiraIssue, mockJiraAttachment);
  }

  private ResponseActions createServiceStub(HttpMethod method, String url, String contenType) {
    String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

    ResponseActions stub = server.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo(url));
    stub = stub.andExpect(method(method));
    stub = stub.andExpect(header("Content-Type", contenType)); // How to expect the content type here ?
    stub = stub.andExpect(header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials));

    return stub;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ContentRequestMatchers.contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType contentType)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/match/ContentRequestMatchers.html#contentTypeCompatibleWith-org.springframework.http.MediaType-)

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.content;
...

stub.andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
```